# How to use the top command to display CPU usage above a certain limit?

Tags: linux, shell, redhat

I wish to use a shell script to filter processes in linux with high CPU usage(more than 80 percent)

**top**

```
PID      USER       PR    NI     VIRT    RES    SHR   S    CPU   MEM   TIME+COMMAND
1        Alan       20    0      4999    444    45    S    1.7   0.8     10:10.00 helloworld
2        Alan       20    0      49993   4443  435    S    8.7   0.8     10:10.00 helloworld
```

Anyone can share ideas on display the PID for those processes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `awk` script like this

```
awk '{ if ($9 > 80 ) print $1}'
```

The full command should be like:

```
top -bn1|awk '{ if ($9 > 80 ) print $0}'
```

This will execute `top` only once and print entire line

Comment: How to print out every column for each row?

Comment: because I try : 
top|awk '{ if ($10 > 0.8 ) print $13,$10}'  it print out very weird output

Comment: @ShiJieTio, check my edited answer

Comment: hi, I wish to skip few line so I have try (-sh-4.2$ top -bn1 | awk '{if ($9 != 0.0) sed -n '8 12p'}') but it return syntax error, anyone can help me on that